# Estava tentando faze uma espécie de calculadora entre dois valor, e existem 6 opções de calculo(Som, Sub, div, raiz quad, potencia e mult

Tags: c

Alguem sabe como ajustar os 8 erros que o compilador achou?
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
float x, y, resultado;
int op;

do{
printf("\n\t1 - SOMA \n\t2 - SUBTAÇÃO\ n\t3 - MULTIPLICAÇÃO \n\t4 - DIVISÃO \n\t5 - POTENCIACAO \n\t6 - RAIZ QUADRADA");
scanf("%d",&op);

```
      printf("\nDigite o primeiro valor: "); 
 scanf("%f", &x);
      printf("\nDigite o segundo valor: "); 
 scanf("%f", &y);
 switch (op){
       case: 1;
    resultado = x+y;
    break;
       case: 2;
    resultado = x-y;
    break;
      case: 3;
    resultado = x*y;
    break;
      case: 4;
    resultado = x/y;
    break;
      case: 5;
    resultado = pow(x,y);
    break;
      case: 6;
    resultado = sqrt (x,y);
    break;
 }
 }while



return 0;
```

}

Answer (score -2):

Dei uma organizada no código, está funcional (lembre-se que a raiz quadrada é só de um número, então ele vai considerar somente o primeiro):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int num1, num2, operacao, resultado;

    printf("Digite os dois números: ");
    scanf("%i%i", &num1, &num2);

    printf("Digite qual operação deseja fazer \n");
    printf("[1] -> Soma\n");
    printf("[2] -> Subtração\n");
    printf("[3] -> Multiplicação\n");
    printf("[4] -> Divisão\n");
    printf("[5] -> Potenciação\n");
    printf("[6] -> Raiz Quadrada\n");
    scanf("%i", &operacao);
    
    switch (operacao){
        case 1:
            resultado = num1 + num2;
        break;
        case 2:
            resultado = num1 - num2;
        break;
        case 3:
            resultado = num1 * num2;
        break;
        case 4:
            resultado = num1 / num2;
        break;
        case 5:
            resultado = pow(num1,num2);
        break;
        case 6:
            resultado = sqrt((double) num1);
        break;
        default:
            printf("Operação Inválida");
            return 0;
        break;
    }
    
    printf("O resultado é: %i\n", resultado);
    
    return 0;
}
```